# Providing a custom error message when HTTP header is invalid (contains whitespace)

Tags: java, spring-boot

Out of the box, spring boot conforms to [RFC7230 section-3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) and returns 400 when header is invalid, example:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization : Basic xxxx" $SOME_URL
```

Here's the relevant excerpt from verbose curl output:

```
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
< content-length: 0
< connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
```

(No body, no explanation)

Extra whitespace before colon is forbidden. Unfortunately, I can't seem to catch that exception and provide a textual body for it. Request doesn't show up in WebFilter, exception is also not caught in AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.  Any tips on how to handle this case?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn first badge.

Answer (score 0):

Though i am not sure how you secure your endpoints, following link might be interesting for you https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler.

Answer (score 0):

Usually to override the way spring treats exception is by extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler I suggest you give these 2 guides a look [1](https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api) [2](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling)